# Subversion: Commit multiple checkouts on different machine for single user

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

On my linux virtual server I have subversion running, everything is working fine. As a single developer I use 1 checkout on my local machine (max osx), edit files, commit and so on, everything is fine.
What I want:
I want a second checkout on a different machine (no problem). On that location I want to edit files (no problem) and commit it to the repository.
So my question:
Is it better (or necessary) to use a second "virtual" user when working with a second checkout directory? - like "simulating" as if there were two developers?
Or is it no problem to use the one and only subversion user I have created managing and working with two or more checkout directories?

Comment: It depends. If you want to check your showlog (later) based on these virtual users, you can commit as different user using
**svn co --username different_user_name** or just leave it. creating multiple virtual user helps you to track

Comment: Don't forget to update the source on machine one when you make changes on machine two.  And vice versa.

Comment: So do I have to checkout as a different user too?

Comment: And one additional question: Do SVN-User and LINUX-User must be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion doesn't mind either way.

Normally, you would use the same user on both machines.

If you consider it useful to use two different accounts, you can do that, too.